# Gracefully Exiting a C Application

Tags: c, shell

I currently have a program I have written in C on a server that has an infinite loop that processes information, each loop takes about 5 minutes to complete. I would like to have the following functionality in a shell script:

- Terminate C program
- Make source
- Run program

The problem is, I don't know how to tell my C program to exit without doing something like ctrl+c, I would rather it finished processing the information it is currently working on before terminating itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The POSIX standard way to tell a process to finish its business and exit cleanly is to send it a `SIGTERM` signal.  Depending on your application it may or may not be appropriate to exit on `SIGINT`, which is meant to interrupt a process, not terminate it.  (Control-c sends `SIGINT`.)

Try putting a flag in your tight loop; check the flag at a time when it is easy to exit, but still frequently enough to exit promptly.  In your case, receipt of a `SIGTERM` might put a message on the system log right away, then promise to exit within the next 5 minutes.

Your signal handler will look like this:

```
static int signalled;  // if nonzero, what signal have we been sent?

static void SignalHandler(int signum) {
  signalled = signum;
}
```

I check the global `static` variable `signalled` after every I/O operation, which means many times per second.

Here's my code to catch and restore signals:

```
static __sighandler_t sh, si, st;

static void catch_signals(void) {
  if ((sh = signal(SIGHUP, SignalHandler)) == SIG_IGN) signal(SIGHUP, SIG_IGN);
  if ((si = signal(SIGINT, SignalHandler)) == SIG_IGN) signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
  if ((st = signal(SIGTERM, SignalHandler)) == SIG_IGN) signal(SIGTERM, SIG_IGN);
  signalled = 0;
}

static void restore_signals(void) {
  signal(SIGHUP, sh);
  signal(SIGINT, si);
  signal(SIGTERM, st);
}
```

(This code is from a library, so I'm being extra careful to leave things the way I found them.)

Bonus trick: when time expires (this is a TV recording library), the timer just sets `signalled = SIGTERM`, and the same logic is used to exit the recorder normally.

Comment: @dear downvoter This is a nice answer. Can you provide a comment to justify the popover text "This answer is not useful" ?

Answer (score 3):

> like ctrl+c, I would rather it finished processing the information it
>   is currently working on before terminating itsel

Establish a signal handler for SIGINT or whatever you want and do your cleanup after you receive it. **You shouldn't do the cleanup in the handler itself** however.

```
volatile sig_atomic_t do_cleanup = 0;
void handler(int sig)
{
    do_cleanup = 1;
}
```

Then in your main loop you just have to test `do_cleanup` and exit when you please. You must also be careful in properly treating `EINTR` errors if you're not already doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to send signal from shell:

http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Sending_signal_to_Processes

or simply `man kill`

Here is how to react to signal:

http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node24.html#SECTION002400000000000000000